# Magento 2 Override Config.xml File to change the status of Braintree Module

Tags: magento2, overrides, configuration

I am trying to override config.xml file of vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/etc  module to changed the "order_status" value from "processing" to "pending" . I have tried it to override by below code:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MyModule_braintree" >
        <sequence>
            <module name="PayPal_Braintree"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

and put the config.xml file in my folder, but its not working. Still module read the core file.
If anyone have idea please share here.

Config.xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <payment>
            <braintree>
                <model>BraintreeFacade</model>
                <title>Credit Card</title>
                <payment_action>authorize</payment_action>
                <active>0</active>
                <is_gateway>1</is_gateway>
                <can_use_checkout>1</can_use_checkout>
                <can_authorize>1</can_authorize>
                <can_capture>1</can_capture>
                <can_capture_partial>1</can_capture_partial>
                <can_authorize_vault>1</can_authorize_vault>
                <can_capture_vault>1</can_capture_vault>
                <can_use_internal>1</can_use_internal>
                <can_refund_partial_per_invoice>1</can_refund_partial_per_invoice>
                <can_refund>1</can_refund>
                <can_void>1</can_void>
                <can_cancel>1</can_cancel>
                <can_edit>1</can_edit>
                <can_review_payment>1</can_review_payment>
                <can_deny_payment>1</can_deny_payment>
                <cctypes>AE,VI,MC,DI,JCB,CUP,DN,MI</cctypes>
                <useccv>1</useccv>
                <cctypes_braintree_mapper><![CDATA[{"american-express":"AE","discover":"DI","jcb":"JCB","mastercard":"MC","master-card":"MC","visa":"VI","maestro":"MI","uk-maestro":"MI","diners-club":"DN","unionpay":"CUP"}]]></cctypes_braintree_mapper>
                <order_status>pending</order_status>
                <environment>sandbox</environment>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
                <public_key backend_model="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted" />
                <private_key backend_model="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted" />
                <masked_fields>cvv,number</masked_fields>
                <privateInfoKeys>avsPostalCodeResponseCode,avsStreetAddressResponseCode,cvvResponseCode,processorAuthorizationCode,processorResponseCode,processorResponseText,liabilityShifted,liabilityShiftPossible,riskDataId,riskDataDecision,transactionSource</privateInfoKeys>
                <paymentInfoKeys>cc_type,cc_number,avsPostalCodeResponseCode,avsStreetAddressResponseCode,cvvResponseCode,processorAuthorizationCode,processorResponseCode,processorResponseText,liabilityShifted,liabilityShiftPossible,riskDataId,riskDataDecision,transactionSource</paymentInfoKeys>
                <kount_allowed_ips>208.75.112.0/22,209.81.12.0/24</kount_allowed_ips>
            </braintree>
            <braintree_paypal>
                <model>BraintreePayPalFacade</model>
                <title>PayPal</title>
                <active>0</active>
                <payment_action>authorize</payment_action>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
                <require_billing_address>0</require_billing_address>
                <allow_shipping_address_override>1</allow_shipping_address_override>
                <display_on_shopping_cart>1</display_on_shopping_cart>
                <order_status>processing</order_status>
                <is_gateway>1</is_gateway>
                <can_use_checkout>1</can_use_checkout>
                <can_authorize>1</can_authorize>
                <can_capture>1</can_capture>
                <can_capture_partial>1</can_capture_partial>
                <can_refund>1</can_refund>
                <can_refund_partial_per_invoice>1</can_refund_partial_per_invoice>
                <can_void>1</can_void>
                <can_cancel>1</can_cancel><can_authorize_vault>1</can_authorize_vault>
                <can_capture_vault>1</can_capture_vault>
                <privateInfoKeys>processorResponseCode,processorResponseText,paymentId</privateInfoKeys>
                <paymentInfoKeys>processorResponseCode,processorResponseText,paymentId,payerEmail</paymentInfoKeys>
                <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                <disabled_funding_checkout></disabled_funding_checkout>
                <disabled_funding_cart></disabled_funding_cart>
                <button_productpage_enabled>0</button_productpage_enabled>

                <!-- These are also defined in Gateway/Config/PayPal/Config.php::getButtonStyle() -->
                <button_customise_cart>0</button_customise_cart>
                <button_color_cart>2</button_color_cart>
                <button_size_cart>2</button_size_cart>
                <button_shape_cart>1</button_shape_cart>
                <button_customise_checkout>0</button_customise_checkout>
                <button_color_checkout>2</button_color_checkout>
                <button_size_checkout>2</button_size_checkout>
                <button_shape_checkout>1</button_shape_checkout>
                <button_customise_productpage>0</button_customise_productpage>
                <button_color_productpage>2</button_color_productpage>
                <button_size_productpage>2</button_size_productpage>
                <button_shape_productpage>1</button_shape_productpage>
            </braintree_paypal>
            <braintree_paypal_credit>
                <model>BraintreePayPalCreditFacade</model>
                <title>PayPal Credit</title>
                <active>1</active>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                <client_id backend_model="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted" />
                <secret backend_model="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted" />
                <sandbox>0</sandbox>
            </braintree_paypal_credit>
            <braintree_cc_vault>
                <model>BraintreeCreditCardVaultFacade</model>
                <title>Stored Cards</title>
            </braintree_cc_vault>
            <braintree_paypal_vault>
                <model>BraintreePayPalVaultFacade</model>
                <title>Stored Accounts (PayPal)</title>
                <can_use_internal>1</can_use_internal>
            </braintree_paypal_vault>
            <braintree_applepay>
                <model>BraintreeApplePay</model>
                <title>Apple Pay</title>
                <active>0</active>
                <payment_action>authorize</payment_action>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
                <require_billing_address>0</require_billing_address>
                <allow_shipping_address_override>0</allow_shipping_address_override>
                <display_on_shopping_cart>0</display_on_shopping_cart>
                <order_status>processing</order_status>
                <is_gateway>1</is_gateway>
                <can_use_checkout>1</can_use_checkout>
                <can_authorize>1</can_authorize>
                <can_capture>1</can_capture>
                <can_capture_partial>1</can_capture_partial>
                <can_refund>1</can_refund>
                <can_refund_partial_per_invoice>1</can_refund_partial_per_invoice>
                <can_void>1</can_void>
                <can_cancel>1</can_cancel>
                <privateInfoKeys>processorAuthorizationCode,processorResponseCode,processorResponseText</privateInfoKeys>
                <paymentInfoKeys>processorAuthorizationCode,processorResponseCode,processorResponseText</paymentInfoKeys>
                <merchant_name>Store</merchant_name>
            </braintree_applepay>
            <braintree_googlepay>
                <model>BraintreeGooglePay</model>
                <title>Google Pay</title>
                <active>0</active>
                <payment_action>authorize</payment_action>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
                <require_billing_address>0</require_billing_address>
                <allow_shipping_address_override>0</allow_shipping_address_override>
                <display_on_shopping_cart>0</display_on_shopping_cart>
                <order_status>processing</order_status>
                <is_gateway>1</is_gateway>
                <can_use_checkout>1</can_use_checkout>
                <can_authorize>1</can_authorize>
                <can_capture>1</can_capture>
                <can_capture_partial>1</can_capture_partial>
                <can_refund>1</can_refund>
                <can_refund_partial_per_invoice>1</can_refund_partial_per_invoice>
                <can_void>1</can_void>
                <can_cancel>1</can_cancel>
                <privateInfoKeys>processorAuthorizationCode,processorResponseCode,processorResponseText</privateInfoKeys>
                <paymentInfoKeys>processorAuthorizationCode,processorResponseCode,processorResponseText</paymentInfoKeys>
                <cctypes>VISA,MASTERCARD,AMEX</cctypes>
                <merchant_id>testmode</merchant_id>
                <btn_color>0</btn_color>
            </braintree_googlepay>
            <braintree_venmo>
                <active>0</active>
                <can_authorize>1</can_authorize>
                <can_cancel>1</can_cancel>
                <can_capture>1</can_capture>
                <can_capture_partial>1</can_capture_partial>
                <can_refund>1</can_refund>
                <can_refund_partial_per_invoice>1</can_refund_partial_per_invoice>
                <can_use_checkout>1</can_use_checkout>
                <can_void>1</can_void>
                <is_gateway>1</is_gateway>
                <model>BraintreeVenmo</model>
                <order_status>processing</order_status>
                <payment_action>authorize</payment_action>
                <title>Venmo</title>
                <privateInfoKeys>processorAuthorizationCode,processorResponseCode,processorResponseText</privateInfoKeys>
                <paymentInfoKeys>processorAuthorizationCode,processorResponseCode,processorResponseText</paymentInfoKeys>
            </braintree_venmo>
            <braintree_ach_direct_debit>
                <active>0</active>
                <can_authorize>1</can_authorize>
                <can_cancel>1</can_cancel>
                <can_capture>1</can_capture>
                <can_capture_partial>1</can_capture_partial>
                <can_refund>1</can_refund>
                <can_refund_partial_per_invoice>1</can_refund_partial_per_invoice>
                <can_use_checkout>1</can_use_checkout>
                <can_void>1</can_void>
                <is_gateway>1</is_gateway>
                <model>BraintreeAch</model>
                <order_status>processing</order_status>
                <payment_action>authorize_capture</payment_action>
                <title>ACH Direct Debit</title>
                <privateInfoKeys>processorAuthorizationCode,processorResponseCode,processorResponseText</privateInfoKeys>
                <paymentInfoKeys>processorAuthorizationCode,processorResponseCode,processorResponseText</paymentInfoKeys>
            </braintree_ach_direct_debit>
            <braintree_local_payment>
                <active>0</active>
                <can_authorize>1</can_authorize>
                <can_cancel>1</can_cancel>
                <can_capture>1</can_capture>
                <can_capture_partial>1</can_capture_partial>
                <can_refund>1</can_refund>
                <can_refund_partial_per_invoice>1</can_refund_partial_per_invoice>
                <can_use_checkout>1</can_use_checkout>
                <can_void>1</can_void>
                <is_gateway>1</is_gateway>
                <model>BraintreeLpm</model>
                <order_status>processing</order_status>
                <payment_action>authorize_capture</payment_action>
                <paymentInfoKeys>processorAuthorizationCode,processorResponseCode,processorResponseText</paymentInfoKeys>
                <privateInfoKeys>processorAuthorizationCode,processorResponseCode,processorResponseText</privateInfoKeys>
                <title>Local Payments</title>
                <allowed_methods>bancontact,eps,giropay,ideal,sofort,mybank,p24,sepa</allowed_methods>
            </braintree_local_payment>
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

Comment: Did you add preference to di.xml file also?

Comment: @AsadUllah , Used but not working.

Comment: @akgola Can you please update with config.xml you are adding.

Comment: did you clean cache and di:compile? @akgola also update question with di.xml file please

Comment: which magento version you are using?

Comment: @RakeshVarma, Magento 2.4 version

Comment: @RahulBarot , updated question  , please check.

Comment: @akgola can you please update question with di.xml file

Answer (score 0):

If a configuration save was previously performed, then no matter how hard we try to overwrite the default config file, the value in the database won't be overwritten.

**My suggestion here is to add a data patch that saves the new configuration programmatically**. This will ensure the values are propagated on any environment you might be using and will overwrite any existing value in the 'core_config_data' table from any previous configuration saves.